# Jfreechart Line chart plots over series when series values are identical

Tags: java, jfreechart, pentaho

I am using Jfreechart in Pentaho to plot an line chart connecting points.  There are seven series of about 6 data points each. Two of the series have the same exact values and therefore the last series plotted is on top of (effectively hiding) the first series plotted. As the product matures it will become less likely for this to occur, but I want our best foot forward from day 1.

Has anybody encountered this before?  Is there a resolution, or workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: what should it do?  AFAIK a lot of charting tools will do that?  What else can be done?

Comment: Y - I don't know, I  was hoping my stupidity was hiding what was an obvious change to everyone else.